# Sum along with subtraction of respective columns in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to show the current stock for the all location along with the location name.Have four tables tables Setup contains branch details,Stockinward contains stock for location along with product Id,Product Outward contains product sales of a particular product,ProductMaster contains deatils of product.here is my sample record and i have tried the below function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[cstock]

(

  @sID int

)

RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)

AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @stckprdt int,@stckprdt1 int,@stockloc varchar(Max);
   select @stckprdt= SUM(Qty)from StockInward where ProductId= @sID group by  StockLocation
  select @stckprdt1=SUM(Qty)from ProductOutward where ProductId= @sID group by Location

   RETURN @stckprdt-@stckprdt1
END

GO
```

ProductMaster

```
ProductId ProductName

1          WashingMachine
2           Fridge
3            Tv
4             Laptop
```

Setup

```
Id  BranchName

1      Chennai

2      Coimbatore

3      Mumbai

4     Cochin
```

StockInward

```
Id  ProductId    StockLocation    Qty

1      1             4             100
2      4             4              10
3      4              1             10
4      3              2             20
5      `1             1             10
```

ProductOutward

```
Id  ProductId    StockLocation    Qty

1        4          4              2
2         1         4              2
```

the output should be

```
orderedproducts       currentstock

Laptop(2)               Cochin(8)
                         Chennai(10)

WashingMachine(2)            Cochin(98)
                           Chennai(10)
```

On the output,currentstock should show the  sum of product for particular location from StockInward -sum of product for particular location from StockOutward

Comment: do you want Laptop to be repeated for both location rows or do you want the location as a csv? your output is not clear. also how did you get (2) in Laptop and nothing in Washing Machine

Comment: No the laptop(2) is the product i ordered,In the product outward table i have ordered  2 laptops and 2 washing machines

Comment: there should be a (2) in washingmachine as well then

Comment: i have to show the currentstock..I have created the function but its not showing the currentstock properly..what will be the solution??

Comment: In stockInward table there is laptop 10 for cochin location,but there is a stockoutward for that so it should be subracted from stockinward so now stock is Cochin(8),and chennai dont have entry in stockoutward so its remains same Chennai(10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
select ProductName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),ProductOutward.Qty)+')' as orderedproducts, BranchName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),StockInward.Qty-ProductOutward.Qty)+')' as currentstock
from ProductMaster 
inner join ProductOutward on ProductMaster.Productid = ProductOutward.productid
inner join stockinward on ProductMaster.Productid = stockinward.productid and stockinward.StockLocation = ProductOutward.StockLocation
inner join Setup on stockinward.stocklocation = Setup.id
union
select ProductName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),0)+')' as orderedproducts, BranchName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),StockInward.Qty)+')' as currentstock
from ProductMaster 
inner join ProductOutward on ProductMaster.Productid = ProductOutward.productid
inner join stockinward on ProductMaster.Productid = stockinward.productid and stockinward.StockLocation <> ProductOutward.StockLocation
inner join Setup on stockinward.stocklocation = Setup.id
```

[image: Fiddle]

**EDIT :** FOR Multiple Stockinwards & ProductOutwards

```
select ProductName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),sum(ProductOutward.Qty)/count(distinct stockinward.id))+')' as orderedproducts
, BranchName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),sum(StockInward.Qty)/count(distinct ProductOutward.id)-sum(ProductOutward.Qty)/count(distinct stockinward.id))+')' as currentstock

from ProductMaster 
inner join ProductOutward on ProductMaster.Productid = ProductOutward.productid
inner join stockinward on ProductMaster.Productid = stockinward.productid and stockinward.StockLocation = ProductOutward.StockLocation
inner join Setup on stockinward.stocklocation = Setup.id

where ProductName = 'laptop'
group by productname,Setup.BranchName--,stockinward.id


union

select ProductName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),0)+')' as orderedproducts, BranchName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),sum(StockInward.Qty))+')' as currentstock
from ProductMaster 
inner join ProductOutward on ProductMaster.Productid = ProductOutward.productid
inner join stockinward on ProductMaster.Productid = stockinward.productid and stockinward.StockLocation <> ProductOutward.StockLocation
inner join Setup on stockinward.stocklocation = Setup.id
where ProductName = 'laptop'
group by ProductName,ProductOutward.Qty,BranchName
```

Check this out :

```
select ProductName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),sum(ProductOutward.Qty)/count(distinct stockinward.id))+')' as orderedproducts
, BranchName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),sum(StockInward.Qty)/count(distinct ProductOutward.id)-sum(ProductOutward.Qty)/count(distinct stockinward.id))+')' as currentstock

from ProductMaster 
inner join ProductOutward on ProductMaster.Productid = ProductOutward.productid
inner join stockinward on ProductMaster.Productid = stockinward.productid and stockinward.StockLocation = ProductOutward.StockLocation
inner join Setup on stockinward.stocklocation = Setup.id

where ProductName = 'laptop'
group by productname,Setup.BranchName--,stockinward.id

union 

select ProductName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),sum(ProductOutward.Qty))+')' as orderedproducts
, BranchName + '(0)' as currentstock

from ProductMaster 
inner join ProductOutward on ProductMaster.Productid = ProductOutward.productid
inner join Setup on ProductOutward.stocklocation = Setup.id

where ProductName = 'laptop' and ProductMaster.ProductId not in (select stockinward.productid from stockinward where stockinward.stocklocation = ProductOutward.stocklocation)
group by productname,Setup.BranchName--,stockinward.id

union 

select ProductName + '(0)' as orderedproducts
, BranchName + '('+convert(nvarchar(10),sum(stockinward.Qty))+')' as currentstock

from ProductMaster 
inner join stockinward on ProductMaster.Productid = stockinward.productid
inner join Setup on stockinward.stocklocation = Setup.id

where ProductName = 'laptop' and ProductMaster.ProductId not in (select ProductOutward.productid from ProductOutward where ProductOutward.stocklocation = stockinward.stocklocation)
group by productname,Setup.BranchName--,stockinward.id
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79648/discussion-on-answer-by-pravin-deshmukh-sum-along-with-subtraction-of-respective).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function, you can use a select statement like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ProductName + 
                '(' + CAST(po.Qty as varchar(10)) + ')', 
                '')  As orderedproducts, 
       BranchName +
       '(' + CAST(si.Qty - COALESCE(po.Qty, 0) As varchar(10)) +')' As CurrentStock 
FROM ProductMaster pm 
INNER JOIN StockInward si ON(pm.ProductId = si.ProductId)
INNER JOIN Setup s ON(si.StockLocation = s.Id)
LEFT JOIN ProductOutward po ON(pm.ProductId = po.ProductId AND po.StockLocation = s.Id)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM ProductOutward
  WHERE ProductId = pm.ProductId
)
ORDER BY ProductName, orderedproducts DESC;
```

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/290b8/1)

**Explanations:**
Using inner joins between `ProductMaster`, `StockInward` and `Setup` gave me all the products in all locations.
Using left join between that and `ProductOutward` allowed me to add the `ProductOutward.Qty` to the product name.
Taking advantage of the fact that concatenating a `null` value to a string in sql server returns a `null` value, I've made sure that only products that are actually sold would appear on the result set.
Using `coalesce` to show null values as empty strings gave me the exact result as the desired result was described.

**Update**
To correctly calculate values where multiple records for the same product and location exists in StockInward and / or in ProductOutward, change the query to use derived tables instead of these to tables directly, like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ProductName + 
                '(' + CAST(po.Qty as varchar(10)) + ')', 
                '')  As orderedproducts, 
       BranchName +
       '(' + CAST(si.Qty - COALESCE(po.Qty, 0) As varchar(10)) +')' As CurrentStock 
FROM ProductMaster pm 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ProductId, StockLocation, SUM(Qty) As Qty
    FROM StockInward 
    GROUP BY ProductId, StockLocation
) si ON(pm.ProductId = si.ProductId)
INNER JOIN Setup s ON(si.StockLocation = s.Id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ProductId, StockLocation, SUM(Qty) As Qty
    FROM ProductOutward 
    GROUP BY ProductId, StockLocation
) po ON(pm.ProductId = po.ProductId AND po.StockLocation = s.Id)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM ProductOutward
  WHERE ProductId = pm.ProductId
)
ORDER BY ProductName, orderedproducts DESC;
```

**Note:** You should probably add a date column for StockInward and ProductOutward to enable questioning the stock in the past.
Currently, your database design only allows to handle current stock.
you can't even tell if the order was placed before or after the stock arrived at the location.

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4194b/1)

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh: Actually, it didn't fail. Note that you have added another row to StockInward with the values (1,1,10) (duplicated), so actually, it's returning  the exact results in should.

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh: [see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf7ac/1) for comparison.

Comment: Sir,Plz help me..Its subracting from both the two entries..Try to duplicate the any of the row for the same location with same productId its subracting from two rows